# Creating randomly generated, secure token and storing in database

Tags: php, security, hash, salt

I am trying to generate a unique token for every user on my site. The token is generated when the user registers, and will ideally be as secure as possble. What is the best method of doing so to allow me to display the token to the user?

This token is NOT a password, and the user is not going to create it themselves. If I hash and salt it upon registration, I will not be able to retrieve it obviously, because it's hashed and salted. I want a simple way to do so via PHP and be able to display it to the user easily.

Comment: Sounds like you want an auto_increment field =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are one-way so the only way to reverse a hash is to store the original value making the hash redundant.

If you only need to display the value once, then store the value into a variable, print it on the page, and don't save it, that's secure for you.

Another option is to just use database encryption to store the token, then decrypt before displaying to the user. Assuming you use MySQL you might find this helpul: [MySQL Encryption](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
md5(uniqid('', true))
```

Comment: How will I retrieve this from the database and print the non-hashed value?

Comment: @seeARMS: you don't need non-hashed value. The hash is a token itself.

Comment: I'd rather not store the token openly in the database... That's the whole point of hashing and salting it. If someone gets access to my database, I want the tokens stored securely.

Comment: @seeARMS: nope, you're just wrong. Open salt doesn't make the hashed data less secured.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do. I want to randomly generate a token, then store it securely in a database. If I stored your code in a database, anyone with access to the database could easily use the token maliciously. I know how to randomly generate a token (which is what you did), however I want a method of storing it securely.

Comment: @seeARMS: lol. Dude, you don't understand what the salt is and what it is used for. Open salt is not a security vulnerability. Here is a salt: `7f4d678b9e7a86d99374033cad979abc`, here is hashed data: `6d710d4d4f3c80b06078d1d23e534587`. **Come on, use it easily, get the initial data.**

Answer (score 0):

not to degrade zerkms' comment. but i would recommend crypt().

what does the non-hashed value do for the user?

Answer (score 0):

How will the user use this token?

The real question is what do you mean by secure.  I am assuming you mean "unguessable", which just means that it has to be long and/or complex.

However that is a problem if the user needs to remember it.

So the real issue is how hard do you want to make it to guess, and how easy do you want it to be recalled?